# Symfony & Sonata : How to add javascript to entity admin form?

Tags: javascript, symfony, sonata

New to Symfony & Sonata I created an entity "Foo" with the associated App\Admin class :

```
<?php 
namespace App\Admin;

final class FooAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {        
        $formMapper
            ->with('Zorg', ['class' => 'col-md-4'])
                ->add('name', TextType::class)
            ->end();
    }
    ...
}
```

Everything works fine. 
I can access the list, add and edit Foo.

I now would like to add a javascript script in the *add* and *edit* forms.

How can I do that? May I have to use assets and Encore?
Is there another/best way?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Encore` then below should work:

```
# config/packages/sonata_admin.yaml

sonata_admin:
  assets:
    extra_stylesheets:
      - build/app.css
    extra_javascripts:
      - build/runtime.js
      - build/app.js
```